# Django ORM converting date to datetime which is slowing down query 30x

Tags: django, postgresql, django-orm, timescaledb

I'm attempting query a table and filter the results by date on a datetime field:
`.filter(bucket__gte = start_date)`  where `bucket` is a datetimefield and `start_date` is a date object.

However django converts the `start_date` to a timestamp in the raw sql ex `2020-02-01 00:00:00` when I want it just be a date ex `2020-02-01`.

For some reason casting `bucket` to a date or casting `start_time` to a timestamp makes the query 30x slower.

When I manually write a query and compare bucket directly to a date ex `bucket >= '2020-02-01'` the query is blazing fast.

How can I get the django orm to do this?

Comment: What is the data type of bucket in the database?

Answer (score 1):

Seems that its most efficient to convert your `date` to a `datetime` in python then do the lookup on the orm since you are filtering on a `DateTimeField`

```
from datetime import datetime


.filter(bucket__gte=datetime.combine(start_date, datetime.min.time()))
```

If the field `bucket` is indexed, the explain of this query should indicate an *Index Scan* which would provide desired and most efficient execution plan.

If not it should still be faster since you avoid casting

Answer (score 0):

> For some reason casting bucket to a date or casting start_time to a timestamp makes the query 30x slower.

Yes, casting bucket to a date would prevent use of an index (unless the index was over the casted column).  But casting start_time to a timestamp would not.  What is it 30 times slower than? You just said python automatically converts it, so, how is that different than casting it?  As in, what is your actual code?

> When I manually write a query and compare bucket directly to a date ex bucket >= '2020-02-01' the query is blazing fast.

OK, but what is it actually doing?

```
explain select * from foo where bucket > '2021-03-01';
                               QUERY PLAN                                
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
 Seq Scan on foo  (cost=0.00..38.25 rows=753 width=8)
   Filter: (bucket > '2021-03-01 00:00:00-05'::timestamp with time zone)
(2 rows)
```

PostgreSQL is also converting it to a timestamp.  Does it give the right answer or the wrong answer?

Comment: I tried experimenting with raw queries. I have two queries, one is filtered ```where bucket >= '2020-01-01'::timestamp and bucket <= '2021-01-01'::timestamp```. This query takes about 34 seconds. I have another query this is identical but the filter is ```where bucket between '2020-01-01' and  '2021-01-01'```. That query takes about 1.3 seconds. I can't figure out why this is.

Comment: Maybe just because the 2nd one has all the data it needs read into the cache by the first one.

Comment: Even if I rerun them after one another this happens. Something is causing it to do an external disk merge

Comment: The issue seems to be the Django orm and how it formats queries. If it didn't add the ```::timestamp``` I wouldn't have an issue

Answer (score 0):

Try convet your datetime to date in filter:

```
.filter(bucket__date__gte = start_date)
```